# How do I make mesos force-pull images when using mesos-execute?

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

Mesos frameworks like Marathon or Chronos have `forcePull`-like options for this, to make mesos agents pull the image from the registry.

Is the same possible with `mesos-execute`? Do I have to specify an option in TaskInfo or TaskGroupInfo?

I have searched in the mesos source for words like "force pull" / "forcepull" or "cached", but no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify a corresponding option in `TaskInfo` to force pull the image. Where exactly — depends on which container type (read: containerizer) you use.

If you use docker containerizer, i.e. your `TaskInfo.container.type = DOCKER`, then have a look at [`ContainerInfo.DockerInfo.force_pull_image`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/396cda9cef532b9be980002d97e4aadf12ccec85/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L2522). What you want to set in your JSON for `TaskInfo` is `TaskInfo.container.docker.force_pull_image = true`.

If you use mesos containerizer, i.e. your `TaskInfo.container.type = Mesos`, then you specify `TaskInfo.container.mesos.image`, which might be a docker or an appc container, and hence should look at [`Image`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/396cda9cef532b9be980002d97e4aadf12ccec85/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L2110), which has a [`cached` flag](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/396cda9cef532b9be980002d97e4aadf12ccec85/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L2164). What you want to set in your JSON for `TaskInfo` is `TaskInfo.container.mesos.image.cached = false`.